# хочу избежать лишних проверок значения при его передаче (из метода в метод)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

хочу избежать лишних проверок значения при его передаче (из метода в метод)
каждый раз проверять значения и бросать исключения затратно, тем более когда шансов поймать ошибку нет

придумал сделать оболочку которая знает что значение проверенно:

```
struct CheckedValue<T>
{
    private readonly T value;
    private CheckedValue(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static CheckedValue<T>? GetCheckedValue(T value, Func<T,bool> check)
    {
        if (check(value))
        {
            return new CheckedValue<T>(value);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

есть другие способы добиться нужного поведения?

Comment: А для чего каждый раз проверять значение при передаче из метода в метод?

Comment: @tym32167 я имею ввиду проверка скорее всего случится 2 раза: например при вызове метода и внутри конструктора структуры

Comment: И почему это проблема? Я просто не вижу тут что то, что надо бы чинить / менять

Comment: А в чем смысл от метода `GetCheckedValue`, если он не является статическим?

Comment: Контракты, Debug.Assert - и в продакшене лишние проверки вырезаются. А так правильно проверять на границе контекста.

Answer (score 5):

То, что вы сделали, чем-то похоже на Value Object, но обладает следующими недостатком - CheckedValue можно создать с разными проверяющими функциями - то есть информация о виде пройденной проверки теряется.

Если внести информацию об ограничении в имя типа - как раз и получится паттерн Value Object.

Пример как может Value Object выглядеть:

```
public struct Temperature
{
    private readonly decimal value;
    private Temperature(decimal value) 
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public decimal ToCelsius => value − 273.15m;
    public decimal ToKelvins => value;
    public decimal ToFahrenheit => value * 1.8m − 459.67m;

    public static Temperature FromCelsius(decimal value) => FromKelvins(value + 273.15m);
    public static Temperature FromFahrenheit(decimal value) => FromKelvins((value + 459.67m) / 1.8m);
    public static Temperature FromKelvins(decimal value) 
    {
        if (value < 0) 
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Такой температуры не бывает");
        return new Temperature(value);
    }

    public static Temperature? TryConvertFromCelsius(decimal value) => TryConvertFromKelvins(value + 273.15m);
    public static Temperature? TryConvertFromFahrenheit(decimal value) => TryConvertFromKelvins((value + 459.67m) / 1.8m);
    public static Temperature? TryConvertFromKelvins(decimal value) 
    {
        if (value < 0) 
            return null;
        return new Temperature(value);
    }

    public static Temperature Zero { get; } = new Temperature(0);
}
```

Отмечу также важную особенность любых структур: структуру можно инициализировать нулями через конструкцию `default(...)` или открытый конструктор по умолчанию (который всегда присутствует и который нельзя переопределить), поэтому если вы делаете Value Object структурой - нужно обязательно убедиться что нулевое значение будет корректным значением.

Если так сделать не получается - то Value Object надо делать классом.

Comment: `default` не обязателен, у структуры *всегда* есть неявный открытый конструктор без параметров

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо за уточнение

Comment: 3 раза прочитал и не понял. Как ваш ответ связан с заданным вопросом?

Comment: @tym32167 напрямую

Comment: @PavelMayorov и где эта связь? Можно поподробней?

Comment: @tym32167 Value Object - это паттерн, который предназначен для передачи между частями программы гарантированно проверенных данных (в примере - температура должна быть больше 0К)

Comment: Хм, всегда думал, что Value Object - это такой неизменяемый объект из DDD, который не является сущностью, но может быть её аттрибутом. В смысле, такой объект, который не требует идентификатора и при записи в хранилище просто перезаписывается поверх предыдущего значения. Подробнее у Эванса в его книжке можно почитать. А то, что вы описали - это типичный неизменяемый объект. Но вот что мне не понятно - почему вы решили, что все объекты, что автор пересылает между функциями - неизменяемые?

Comment: Ну и определение `Value Object` меня сбило, я не понял, причем тут DDD, потому и спросил

Comment: @tym32167 потому что CheckedValue из вопроса - неизменяемый

Comment: То, что в вопросе, не неизменяемый объект, так как если T- класс с пропертями, то его вполне можно поменять, а эта конструкция хранит не копию класса, а ссылку на класс. Да и вообще конструкция непонятно что делает - сохраняет значение, но никогда его не отдает. Хотя теперь движение вашей мысли я уловил, спасибо. Теперь понятно как ответ соотносится с вопросом.

Comment: @tym32167 да, дочерние свойства value в вопросе можно поменять. Но, судя по описанию решаемой задачи (избежать лишних проверок) - это скорее баг чем фича

Comment: Ну я просто подумал, что автор переизобретает контракты, мол проверки на Null, проверки на какую то базовую логику, на те условия, что являются предусловиями/постусловиями для методов. И он не хочет делать это для каждой функции (и не должен по идее). И у меня в голове это никак не состыковывалось с вашим ответом.